# My mouse is inverted, no clue why, natural scolling doesnt work

Tags: mouse

My touchpad works fine, but my mouse does not, for some reason i have to move the mouse right to go left. I tired looking into the settings but nothing works, not even natural scrolling. Help is appreciated

Comment: possible hardware fault? try a different mouse or clean the base and/or the mat you are using... Which version of Ubuntu are you using?